KL Divergence larger than Conditional KL Divergence
Let $q(z|y)$ and $r(z)$ be variational approximations of $p(z|y)$ and $p(z)$, respectively. If I know that $H(q(z|y))=H(r(z))$, where $H$ is the entropy, I'd like to know if it is true that:
\begin{equation}
    KL\left(p(z)||r(z)\right) \geq KL\left(p(z|y)||q(z|y)\right)
\end{equation}
where $KL$ is the KL divergece.
My intuition is telling me that it's true but I haven't managed to formally prove it.
Thanks in advance to the community.


A notation question: by $H(q(z|y))$ do you mean $H(q(\cdot|y))$ for a fixed value of $y$, or do you mean a conditional entropy such as $\sum p(y) H(q(\cdot|y))$? Similarly, what is $\mathrm{KL}( p(z|y) |q(z|y))?$ 2. What did you try, and where are you stuck? You say you haven't managed to prove it, so surely gave it a shot before posting? Put this attempt in the question.

